# На чем реализовать приложение?

Tags: android, mysql, база-данных, windows

Есть задача сделать приложение, которое будет работать и на Windows и на Android. Это будет платформа, в которую зарегистрированные пользователи будут заносить информацию о проделанной работе (связано со строительством) и информацию по закупкам. Эта информация должна передаваться от одного отдела к другому в этом же приложении. Первое что пришло в голову это C# с mySQL. Может быть есть более подходящие варианты для этой задачи?

Comment: А как андроиды будут коннектится к MySQL серверу ? Они всегда подключены к корпоративной WiFi или будете MySQL в интернет выставлять ? Если второе, то как будет работать авторизация пользователей, каждый пользователь будет заводиться как пользователь БД ? (иначе пароль для mysql надо будет как то в приложение зашивать, что не безопасно)

Comment: Ввиду всего этого может сделать Web-приложение (что бы из любого бразуера работать) или при Web-API и поверх него отдельно сайт и приложение

Comment: @Mike А есть какие-нибудь инструменты, если будет делаться веб-приложение, которые бы позволили пользователям вносить информацию без доступ в интернет, а когда они бы подключались к сети, то информация бы выгружалась на сервер?

Comment: Не слышал о таком (но это не говорит что такого нет) Я бы в таком случае наверно все таки делал десктопное приложение с временным хранением в какой нибудь sqlite и переливанием в центральную БД при соединении с интернетом. В принципе sql хранилище сейчас и в браузерах доступно, но приложение все таки при подключенном интернете запускать придется

Comment: Но в любом случае общаться с сервером лучше все таки через api (который проще всего делать на web). чем коннектится к БД напрямую из приложения

Comment: @mike Не много не правильно сформулировал, на ПК доступ в интернет будет всегда. Такая функция только для приложения для мобильного устройства нужна. Чтобы пользователь например заполнил какую-нибудь таблицу, даже если у него нет интернета, а когда бы интернет появился, то он бы мог нажать кнопку "загрузить".

Comment: ну тогда точно web-api через которое будет работать android приложение с временным хранением в каком нибудь sqlite или может на андроидах что то другое готовое есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

сделать PWA приложение, на компах будет работать в браузере, на андроидах и айфонах будет как приложение. Наверное можно и на c# такое сделать. по сути сайт